# ReactJS: function Returing [object, object]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form that I use for the creation and for the edit.

If I'm in the edit method, I use this part:

```
 PersonEntity && PersonEntity.entCod ? (
                          <AvInput id="person-entCod" data-cy="entCod" className="form-control" name="entCod" readOnly>
                            {findNameEnte(PersonEntity.entCod)}
                          </AvInput>
                        ) : ''
```

so because of I don't have the name in PersonEntity I create a method to find the name and then return it:

```
  const findNameEnte = codeEnte => {
const option = Entes.find(element => element.entCod.toString() === codeEnte.entCod.toString());
    return JSON.stringify(option.entDesente);
}
```

My problem is that

```
return JSON.stringify(option.entDesente);
```

return me [Object, Object]

How can I do to return the value?

Comment: you can just simply return the name value why you need to use JSON.stringify ?

Comment: I have tried without JSON.stringify but it is the same [object, object]

Comment: maybe the problem should be in the <AvInput....> where I use name="entCod"

Answer (score 0):

[object Object] is a string version of an object instance. This value is returned by a JavaScript program if you try to print out an object without first formatting the object as a string.

So if you are using  JSON.stringify your function must be return string. Maybe you need to check "<AvInput>"

you can try to use arrow function maybe this is solves your problem.

{() => findNameEnte(PersonEntity.entCod)}

You can find more here:
https://careerkarma.com/blog/javascript-object-object/

Comment: I have tried using the arrow function, but in this way it doesn't call the function findNameEnte. :(